# Can I get q value form a RTSP streaming using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I can get fps, framerate information from ffmpeg,

But How to get Q value of the stream ?

`ffmpeg -y -t 5  -i rtsp://172.19.1.42/live.sdp -acodec copy -vcodec copy lala.avi`

Answer (score 1):

You can not get the Q value unless the encoder stores it in the file metadata some place. quality is simply one form of rate control. If the video was encoded with ABR then the quantizer value can change continuously.